# Error in executing a command in Ubuntu

Tags: server, command-line

I am a newbie to Ubuntu. When I execute a command in a terminal I get an error. The command is:

```
$ ./h_affine.ln -haraff -i img1.ppm -o img1.haraff -thres 1000
```

The error is:

```
modglue::ext_process::fork: execvp failed.
```

The above command is for converting an image to an array of values. Please help to sort this out. I have no idea what this error means.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to tell what the underlying problem might be from just that message. Try tracing the process, and see what happens:

```
strace -f ./h_affine.ln -haraff -i img1.ppm -o img1.haraff -thres 1000
```

Capture the output, search for "exec", and see if there are any clues about what the problem was. Basically, `strace` just lists all the kernel calls a program uses as it runs. This is very handy because all the things you imagine a program doing (messing with data, etc.) is just internal detail - `strace` captures everything it actually *does*.

Comment: Thank u sir. I traced the process using the above command. But I couldn't understand what I have to do to rectify the errors.

Comment: Well, it looks like it's trying to execute some program, but the error doesn't show what. If `strace` shows a call to `fork` returning an error, your box may be out of resources (too many processes, or too little memory).  If it shows a call to `exec` failing, the child program failed to start for some reason.  If it doesn't show a call to `exec` at all, it probably means the child program couldn't be found in the first place.